# Can I have a double task on the same line in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, tasks, ms-project-2013

Suppose I have a task that is being stopped for a while and then it continues.

I would like to show that like recurrent tasks , is this possible with manual tasks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can split the tasks.  However, depending on why it stops and starts, might be better to create a separate task on another line.

Comment: How to do that split ?? Please ?

Comment: @OSryx Select the task that you want to split and click on the "Split Task" button in the Task ribbon. A split will be introduced at the "completed-to" point and you can then move the rightmost section to a new date. This works for auto and manual scheduled tasks.

Comment: can you edit the answer so that I validate it :)

Comment: and I need more details about the fields/columns updated with the new dates .... can you help please @MarvMills

Comment: @OSryx Add new questions on this site (i.e. not tagged on to this question, answer or comments) and I and the community may be able to help. We do not offer 1-on-1 consultation!

Comment: hhhh okey @MarvMills